# Upgrading Server 2003 to Server 2008, any good checklists?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm upgrading from Server 2003 to Server 2008 for a domain with 100 users.
Any good check-lists out there for things to think about for moving the users.

Comment: Moving the users? Are you upgrading the current domain and server or migrating to a new domain and server?

Comment: What are you upgrading? Is this the only server? Is it running AD, Exchange, File Services, Print Services, etc? Is it an in-place upgrade or do you have new hardware for it? You need to give more details if you want a useful answer.

Comment: This is a small domain with AD, Exchange, Sharepoint, Print server, and MSSQL. We do have all new hardware and we're testing 64 bit 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you are upgrading a domain controller. You want to add the new server as a member server and promote it to a domain controller and allow replication to happen. Then transfer all requisite roles to it and demote the original server to a member server. It is then safe to unjoin it and decommission as usual.

Make sure you have current working backups before doing any of this.

If you want to upgrade your only DC from 2003 to 2008, don't.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you put it on new hardware and deploy the x64 version if possible especially in Exchange enviroments. Microsoft has huge toolkit called [MAP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=67240b76-3148-4e49-943d-4d9ea7f77730&DisplayLang=en). I highly recommend RTF because there are many variables to this type of upgrade.